# Angular 4/Ionic 3 slides application

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic3, ion-slides

On initialization of the app, I'm pulling [json](/questions/tagged/json)file from server with `DATETIME` describing epoc time at which I should be displaying certain image. Even though I'm able to trigger first slide change, I cannot wrap my head around triggering consecutive slides.

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AlertController, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Slides } from 'ionic-angular';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { FileTransfer, FileTransferObject } from '@ionic-native/file-transfer';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';
// declare var cordova:any;

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
   templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  @ViewChild(Slides) slides:Slides
  fetchedImages: any;
  images: any;

  imageURI: any;
  imageFileName: any;
  // storageDirectory = cordova.file.directory;

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public http: Http,
    private transfer: FileTransfer,
    private alertCtrl: AlertController,
    private file: File

  ) {
       this.http.get('http://solosnet.com/signage/test.cfm')
       .map(res=> res.json())
        .subscribe(data=> {
          this.images = data;
        }
       );
    }


   goToNext(index, time) {
     var multiplied = time*1000;
     var eta_ms = multiplied - Date.now();
     console.log(eta_ms);
     setTimeout(()=> {
       this.slides.slideNext();
       console.log('Fired!');
      }, eta_ms);
    }

    startSlides() {
      if ( this.images !== undefined) {
        this.goToNext(1, this.images[1].DATETIME);
      }
    }

    slideChanged() {
      let currentIndex = this.slides.getActiveIndex();
      let nextIndex = currentIndex + 1;
      console.log('Current index is ', currentIndex);

      this.goToNext(nextIndex, this.images[nextIndex].DATETIME);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to create a schedule that will jump to next slide every time `Date.now` equals `DATETIME` in `JSON` object?

```
[
   {
     UUID: "uuid-johna1",
     FILE: "http://movieaddigital.com/output/ba3390-
            013f1255f293cfc4334c569d55f6682f-5_1920x1080.jpg",
     DATETIME: 1510767348
   },
   {
     UUID: "uuid-john2a",
     FILE: "http://movieaddigital.com/output/ho1199-       
            5e01d368ebc1e2fcc5be429c315afe9e_1920x1080.jpg",
     DATETIME: 1510767468
   }
]
```

Finally my HTML

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-slides *ngIf="images" class="image-slider" loop="false" 
slidesPerView="1" (ionSlideDidChange)="slideChanged()">
        <ion-slide *ngFor="let img of images ">
            <img [src]="img.FILE" class="slide-image" /> 
       </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Can you share what your JSON object is? This sounds like a great application for an rxjs solution.

Comment: You can't even trigger a second one is that it ? Can you also show us the slides html code ?

Comment: I can trigger second one and consecutive ones but they won't do the timeout and are being fired almost same time.